# Creating a new list starting from the list elements of another list (nested lists)

Tags: r, list

in my dataset `LISTS` is a list of lists. Suppose it is composed by 3 lists, each of those made up by 3 matrices. Hence I have 9 matrices in total:

```
A <- list(matrix(rep(1.1,4),ncol=2), 
          matrix(rep(1.2,4),ncol=2), 
          matrix(rep(1.3,4),ncol=2))

B <- list(matrix(rep(2.1,4),ncol=2),
          matrix(rep(2.2,4),ncol=2), 
          matrix(rep(2.3,4),ncol=2))

C <- list(matrix(rep(3.1,4),ncol=2),
          matrix(rep(3.2,4),ncol=2),
          matrix(rep(3.3,4),ncol=2))

LIST <- list(A,B,C)
```

What I need to do is to create a new list composed by three lists. The first one made up by the lower-level matrices `A[[1]]`, `B[[1]]`, `C[[1]]`; the second by `A[[2]]`, `B[[2]]`, `C[[2]]`, and the last one by `A[[3]]`, `B[[3]]`, `C[[3]]`.

At first I tried to isolate single matrices with, for instance, `LIST[[1]][[1]]` and so on. This works, but then I didn't find the corret syntax for selecting 3 matrices at one time. What I mean (with wrong syntax) is to select the first matrix of each list by using something like `LIST[(1:3)][[1]]`, which is clearly wrong...

In other words, I am wondering whether there is a direct way for selecting a subset of a nested list (similarly to what it is possible to do with matrices or dataframes)

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: How would _you_ proceed?

Comment: I wasn't being rude at all. One of the things you are supposed to include in your questions is what you have attempted thus far. That way, we don't suggest things you have already tried.

Comment: Just put that in your question. Everyone _says_ that they've been trying stuff for hours/days, but on the internet anyone can say that. If your question is simply "I need to do X, tell me how" that comes across as, well, _rude_.

Comment: ok, thanks for all your advices

Comment: Do you have an answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are just looking for `[[` within `lapply`, but your question is not very clear.

For example, to get the third element from each of the sublists:

```
lapply(LIST, `[[`, 3)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  1.3  1.3
# [2,]  1.3  1.3
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  2.3  2.3
# [2,]  2.3  2.3
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  3.3  3.3
# [2,]  3.3  3.3
```